# Unicode support in Java SE7: missing classes for Unicode scripts?

Tags: regex, unicode, java-7

I'm trying to capture Arabic text using the java regular expression `\\p{IsArabic}`, however the java compiler does not seem to recognize it,  [even though the documentation for java SE7 says it does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

I am pretty sure I'm using the correct compiler (JDK 1.7).  In fact, the compiler is not recognizing any of the script classes, such as `\\p{IsLatin}` and `\\p{IsGreek}` !  Is anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: `Pattern.compile("\\p{IsGreek}").matcher("\u03A9").matches()` evaluates to true on Oracle Java 1.7.0_02-b13 on Win32.

Comment: @McDowell, many thanks! Indeed it seems I was simply using the wrong JDK version after all; I had both JDK 1.6 and 1.7 installed on my system and NetBeans somehow insisted on using 1.6, so I just uninstalled it to be safe. Interestingly, the Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS flag that beerbajay had mentioned in his (now removed) comment is only needed to revert to Unicode 6.0's definition of character classes...good to know!

Comment: @ChirazBenAbdelkader If you solved your problem then you should post your answer then accept it. Or close the question.

Comment: @LarryBattle  Thanks for the reminder.  Indeed my problem has long been solved, as indicated in my note to McDowell above.  Not really sure if there is anything else I need to do to "officially" close the question.